# How to make full screen image grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout like the image below,
however the problem is that the layout needs to be a ***full screen*** on 
desktop devices but i am not able to make it. If you run ***code snippet*** in ***full screen/Full page*** you can see that there is **white gap** below it (not full screen).

So how to make layout like this in full window/screen?
Is it possible?

[image]

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  
}

.container{
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
display: table;

}

.nav{
 background:#1c1c1c;
 width:250px;
 height:100%;
 display: table-cell;
 

}

img {
     width: 100%;
}

#small_wrap{
 background:white;
 max-width:100%;
 padding-right: 0.2%;
 padding-left: 0.2%;
 padding-bottom: 0.2%;
 padding-top: 0.2%;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#small_wrap > div{
    /*background:#2C3E50;*/
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom: 0.2%;
}


#small_wrap > div{
    width: 24%;
    /*padding-bottom : 23.3%;*/
    margin: 0.5%;
 margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
  
  </div><!--/nav-->
  
  
  <div id="small_wrap">
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
 <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
 <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
 <div><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vSD6fCX.png"></div>
 
 
</div>
  
  </div><!--/container-->
 

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new css grid layout so you will have full control of cells. [Check the compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid)

**NOTE:** You can use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));` if you want to wrap the columns and have the blank space at the bottom. More about the new css grid layout module [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.Grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(100px, 1fr)); /* The first value is the columns number */
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
}

.Cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 8px;
}

.Cell::before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">
  <div class="Cell">Cell 01</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 02</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 03</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 04</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 05</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 06</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 07</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 08</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 09</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 10</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 11</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 12</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 13</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 14</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 15</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 16</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 17</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 18</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 19</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 20</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 21</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 22</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 23</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 24</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 25</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 26</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 27</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 28</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 29</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 30</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 31</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 32</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 33</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 34</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 35</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 36</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 37</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 38</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 39</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 40</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 41</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 42</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 43</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 44</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 45</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 46</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 47</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 48</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 49</div>
  <div class="Cell">Cell 50</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing this:

```
#small_wrap > div{
    width: 24%;
    /*padding-bottom : 23.3%;*/
    margin: 0%;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

and this:

```
#small_wrap{
    background:white;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Nope, the elements needs to be floated just like in the screenshot.

Comment: Note that you have two definitions of "#small_wrap > div{" you can leave the first as it is and change the second as I suggested,  it is always better to merge them, in any case...